# How to have two event on the same elements ? (click and unclick)

Tags: javascript

I have this function that triggered when I click on `<li>`element (click).
I want to triggered another function when I click on the same `<li>` element (unclick).

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>Option1</li>
    <li>Option2</li>
    <li>Option3</li>
    <li>Option4</li>
    <li>Option5</li>
    <li>Option6</li>
    </ul>




<script>  
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.addEventListener("click", addToArray));

function addToArray() {

 }

</script>
```

Please, I am looking for code with plain JavaScript that could do the trick.
Thank You

Comment: What happens after the first click?

Comment: Sorry about that. I had no idea how to do it that why i asked in the first place. I am not asking you guys to write the code for me that why I have it in general form. all my attempts don't make any sense. Now, after you showed me ".toggle and .contains " in your answer, I could have my own attempts.@RobG

Comment: No worries. Just be careful of using new features, there are still many browsers in use that do not support arrow functions or ECMAScript 2015 features. Even using IE10, many pages trip it into IE7 mode and do browser sniffing so refuse to serve content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can toggle a class value and do something based on whether it's present or not, e.g.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('li'), function(li) {
    li.addEventListener('click',handleClick,false);
  });
};

function handleClick(){
  this.classList.toggle('selected');
  if (this.classList.contains('selected')) {
    console.log(this.textContent + ' is selected');
  } else {
    console.log(this.textContent + ' isn\'t selected');
  }
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>First
  <li>Second
  <li>Third
</ol>
```

Note that *classList* requires IE 10 or greater. The same functionality can be coded fairly simply if older browsers need to be supported. The following uses a *classList* object to provide the same functionality and will work back to IE 6.

```js
// Helper object to provide classList functionality
var classList = {
  contains: function(el, className) {
    var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + className + '(\\s|$)');
    return re.test(el.className);
  },
  add: function (el, className) {
    if (!classList.contains(el, className)) {
      el.className += ' ' + className;
    }    
  },
  remove: function(el, className) {
    if (classList.contains(el, className)) {
      var re = new RegExp('(^|\\s)' + className + '(\\s|$)');

      el.className = el.className.replace(re, ' ');
    }    
  },
  toggle: function(el, className) {
    if (classList.contains(el, className)) {
      classList.remove(el, className);
    } else {
      classList.add(el, className);
    }
  }
};

window.onload = function() {
  var lis = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
  for (var i=0, iLen=lis.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    lis[i].addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);
  }
};

function handleClick(){
  classList.toggle(this, 'selected');
  if (classList.contains(this, 'selected')) {
    console.log(this.innerHTML + ' is seleced');
  } else {
    console.log(this.innerHTML + ' is not seleced');
  }
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
    <ol>
      <li>First
      <li>Second
      <li>Third
    </ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>  
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
Array.from(elems).forEach(v => { 
    v.addEventListener("click", addToArray));

function addToArray(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.includes('active')) {
        event.target.classList.split("active").join("");
        // unclick handler here
    } else {
        event.target.classList.push("active");
        // click handler here
    }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
Array.from(elems).forEach(v => v.addEventListener("click", addToArray));

function addToArray() {
  this.classList.toggle('selected');

  if ( this.classList.contains('selected') ) {
     console.log('Selected item');
     }
  else {
    //Do something else
  }
 }
```